# Sqlite full text search keyword 'Match' not returning any result

Tags: sql, sqlite, full-text-search, fts4

I am working on `full text search` on `sqlite` using `fts4`.

In my DB I have a normal table `Notes` and it contains `33 records`.

I created a virtual table using `fts4` like this

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE t3 USING fts4(content="Notes", user_notes);
```

I am querying it like this

```
SELECT user_notes FROM t3 WHERE user_notes MATCH 'important'
```

And this

```
SELECT user_notes FROM t3 WHERE t3 MATCH 'important'
```

But non of the query is working, Why? I am getting empty result no error.

Comment: You get an empty result because there are not matching rows.

Comment: @CL. Please tell how I am not matching the row in this query SELECT user_notes FROM t3 WHERE user_notes MATCH 'important' ..... user_note is the row.....

Comment: What row? Why are you assuming that there is a matching row?

Comment: @CL. Yes in my row user_note I have 'important' word, then why its not matching

Comment: Show that row (with a SELECT, or the code that is inserting it).

Comment: @CL. I create the fts4 table like this CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE t3 USING fts4(content="Notes", user_notes); ..... when I query SELECT * FROM t3, I can see all 33 user notes. If I insert new row in Notes table it is automatically in t3 table also. Now I am querying t3 SELECT user_notes FROM t3 WHERE user_notes MATCH 'important' I don't get any result, But if I replace Match with = I get the result..... Why Match keyword is not returning any result?

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#_external_content_fts4_tables_) says:

> The FTS4 module never writes to the content table, and writing to the content table does not affect the full-text index. It is the responsibility of the user to ensure that the content table and the full-text index are consistent.

So when you insert into the `Notes` table, you must also insert into the `t3` table.
(If the actual table is already filled, use the `rebuild` FTS command.)

Comment: CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE t3 USING fts4(content="Notes", user_notes);  after this query when I select like this SELECT * FROM t3 I can see all the records, I didn't insert any record explicitly, then why its showing all the records?

Comment: Becaus it isn't using the index (this is the whole point of an external content table).

Comment: means after this CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE t3 USING fts4(content="Notes", user_notes); I have to insert data in t3, then Match keyword will work?

Answer (score -7):

Have you tried using the 'LIKE' operator instead?

```
SELECT user_notes FROM t3 WHERE user_notes LIKE'%important%'
```

Comment: We should use FTS for searching